# Setup span in StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I need to create a view like the following (this is an iOS screenshot since I've already created it).

Each blue box is part of a linear layout of a `RecyclerView`, while each green item is part of a staggered layout.

I'm able to create that structure. The problem is that I cannot make each gray box half of the yellow box. Using the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` I'm not able to control the span (size) of the boxes that appear for the inner recycler view. Only a `GridLayoutManager` has the chance to set a span size lookup.

The desiderata is to calculate the boxes based on the with of the container. For example: if the screen is 99, the yellow box should be 66 while the gray 33.

Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Here a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
public class BoxViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BoxViewAdapter.BoxViewHolder> {
    private List<Box> mValues;
    private Context mContext;
    protected BoxViewAdapter.ItemListener mListener;

    public BoxViewAdapter(Context context, List<Box> values, BoxViewAdapter.ItemListener itemListener) {
        mValues = values;
        mContext = context;
        mListener = itemListener;
    }

    @Override
    public BoxViewAdapter.BoxViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.box_view_item, parent, false);
        return new BoxViewAdapter.BoxViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BoxViewAdapter.BoxViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(mValues.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public interface ItemListener {
        void onItemClick();
    }

    public class BoxViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public Box item;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;

        public BoxViewHolder(View v) {

            super(v);

            v.setOnClickListener(this);

            StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
            recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.cardRecyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
        }

        public void bind(Box item) {
            this.item = item;
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new CardViewAdapter(itemView.getContext(), item.cards, null));
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I've resolved this way.

In `onBindViewHolder` of `CardViewAdapter` I simply set `LayoutParams` for `itemView`. Since the item view is the rendered inside a `RecyclerView`, `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` knows how to deal with it.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    if (mUseLayoutParameters) {
        int singleScreenWidth = DisplayUtils.getScreenWidth() / 3;
        Card card = mValues.get(position);
        if (card.isDoubleSized) {
            singleScreenWidth = singleScreenWidth * 2;
        }

        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams(singleScreenWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    viewHolder.bind(mValues.get(position));
}
```